# Select / deselect UIButton when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode5

I have a simple question which I cannot seem to find an answer for.

I have several `UIButton`s which are stored in an `NSArray`, with a `for` loop to set `button.selected = YES` when they are tapped. I need to deselect the same button when it is tapped, but I can't seem to find anything online to help. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_asbBtn, _vwfBtn, _bpBtn, _rtaBtn, _mslmBtn, _pbaBtn, _rcfBtn, _mspBtn, _wpBtn, _aawBtn, _ppiBtn, _convBtn, nil];

    // Select buttons
    for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
        if (button == sender) {
            button.selected = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this is not the best approach, sorry if I am missing something simple. I have tried adding `else { button.selected = NO;` but this only allows one button to be selected and deselects all others. Please can someone guide me in the right direction to deselect the current selected button when tapped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to toggle between *selected* and *unselected* states each time you click on a `UIButton` instance, you can use the Objective-C code below:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setSelected: NO];
    } else {
        [sender setSelected: YES];
    }
}
```

Note that you can have the same result with an even shorter implementation:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [sender setSelected: ![sender isSelected]];
}
```

---

With Swift 3, you would use the following code:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I like the short code version so I will implement that!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you even doing it that way? That is so overly complicated. The simple way is to do this

```
- (IBAction)reasonTapped:(id)sender 
{
    // Personal preference here but I would check to make sure
    // that the sender is actually a button.
    if([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        // Sender will be the button that is pressed.
        if([sender isSelected]) {
            // If already selected then set to selected to NO
            [sender setSelected:NO];
        } else {
            // Else set to selected to YES
            [sender setSelected:YES];
        } 
    } else {
        // Else if not an instance of UIButton throw some sort of warning.
    }
}
```

If you have linked all your buttons up correctly either in your code or in interface/storyboards when the user presses a button it will call this method and `sender` will be that button that is pressed. So no need for the redundant array at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You're right, it looks like I have over complicated a simple task. I have up-voted your answer because it's a useful explanation, but I have decided to go with POB's implementation of just one line.

Comment: That's fine it's up to you which one is more helpful. Good coding.

Answer (score 2):

bind all button with this single IBAction

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 -(IBAction)reasonTapped:(id)sender{
           if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setSelected: NO];
    } else {
        [sender setSelected: YES];
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a pretty easy way to solve this. My example is for 2 buttons but you can easily add more if statements for additional buttons. Connect all buttons to the .h file as properties and name them (I did button1 & button2). Place the following code in your .m file and Connect it (via the storyboard) to all of your buttons. Make sure when you are setting up your button to set an image for BOTH the normal UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateSelected or this wont work.

```
- (IBAction)selectedButton1:(id)sender {

if ([sender isSelected]) {
    [sender setSelected:NO];

    if (sender == self.button1) {
        [self.button2 setSelected:YES];
    }
    if (sender == self.button2) {
        [self.button1 setSelected:YES];
    }
}

else
{
    [sender setSelected:YES];

    if (sender == self.button1) {
        [self.button2 setSelected:NO];
    }
    if (sender == self.button2) {
        [self.button1 setSelected:NO];
    }

}
```